# Why isn't the off-topic reason for closing the question shown?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons, off-topic

I have found a question on Drupal Answers with 4 closing votes.

> [image: screenshot]

As moderator, I wanted to see what reason was chosen, but I don't see it.

> [image: screenshot]

Why does it happen? This is the first time I see something similar.

The question is https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105463/cant-register-to-entity-using-registrations-module, asked on March of this year. For what I recall, there aren't any closing reason that we removed after that question was asked.

Comment: Could these be old close reasons that have been retired?

Comment: We didn't remove off-topic reasons; we didn't changed them since before the question was asked, as far as I know.

Comment: There _is_ one deactivated close reason that talks about typographical errors - you sure this wasn't ever used?

Comment: @TimPost It seems a first tentative to write the second closing reason. As far as I recall, it was never used. It was also added and removed before March 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tim surmised, this was because these voters all chose a reason that was later deactivated.

You can access a complete list of past and current off-topic reasons using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer: https://data.stackexchange.com/drupal/query/187951

As you can see, the reason in question was approved on January 20th and then later deactivated on March 26th. The votes on that question accumulated during the period this reason was active.

Fortunately, [y'all are getting through some of your backlog now](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/134-posts-awaiting-review-where), so this should be less common in the future.